# Append element to :eq(2) if there are 3 or more on the page, or :eq(1) if there are less than 3

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a page that has a variable number of elements with the class `.def-set`. On some pages it could have as many 60 of them, and on others, it could have as few as 1.

I have been able to appended an element, `.editorial-content-feed-replacement`, after the 3rd instance of the `.def-set` class, which is what we want, but I'm wondering now if there is a way to append it after the first or second instance of `.def-set` if there are less than 3 on the page.

My current code: `$('.def-set:eq(2)').append('.editorial-content-feed-replacement')`

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the number of `.def-set` elements with

```
let num = $(".def-set").length
```

and then compare with if-else logic to accomplish what you want:

```
if (num >= 3) {
  $('.def-set:eq(2)').append('.editorial-content-feed-replacement');
} else {
  // This will append it after the last .def-set element
  $('.def-set').append('.editorial-content-feed-replacement');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of elements in .defSet using length - then set an index to either 1 or 2 depending on the outcome;

Note the ternary operator in the following  - this is a shorthand way of saying - if(length < 3){ index = 1 } else { index = 2 };

```
var defSetLength = $('.def-set').length;
var index;
defSetLength < 3 ? index = 1 : index = 2;
$('.def-set:eq(index)').append('.editorial-content-feed-replacement');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).

Example using two lists of different length:

```js
$('#list-one li').slice(0,3).last().append(' - Appended content');
$('#list-two li').slice(0,3).last().append(' - Appended content');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>List one</strong>
<ul id="list-one">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<strong>List two</strong>
<ul id="list-two">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```